# PHP Regular Expression for State Abbreviations

Tags: php, regex

I realize SO isn't the "make me a regex" site, but I've honestly attempted to solve this on my own for a while. I am terrible at regular expressions.

Basically, I am parsing a query for a location search which could include all sorts of variations like "Area, City, State, Zip" and everything in between (with or without commas), abbreviated states or spelled out, etc.

I am struggling with the state abbreviation. Mostly because it doesn't always have a space on either side like " VA ", instead it may be the end of the string. I've been testing these in a [RegEx tool](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php), and here are a couple I've tried for "VA":

> /( VA)(\s|\n|\r)/   <-- DOESNT WORK AT ALL
>
> /( VA)[^A-Z0-9]*/   <-- ENDS UP ALLOWING NUMBERS AND LETTERS ON THE END

I guess I just need some guidance on how to go about doing this?

[EDIT] @Igor Korghov

I have an array of state abbreviations with coast lines:

```
$stateAbbreviations  = Array('AL','AK','CA','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','LA','ME','NH','NJ','NY','NC','OR','MD','MA','MS','RI','SC','TX','VA','WA');
```

Later in my code, I am looping through these and trying to match them in my $query which as been uppercased with strtoupper().

```
$query = "LESNER BRIDGE, VIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453";

foreach($this->stateAbbreviations as $state)
{
   if(preg_match("/( VA)[^A-Z0-9]*/", $query, $match))
   {                    
      var_dump($match);
   }
}
```

I realize a more efficient way is to just find isolated 2 character blocks and then compare to my array, but for the moment, I'm just messing around testing to make sure I can even grab the abbreviation.

Comment: Please define some strings, the regexp should match

Comment: @IgorKorkhov I added some more information.

Comment: @DerVO I'm not looking for a catch-all solution to the whole string. Just a way to match a two letter word that ensures there are no other characters just before or just after it. So " VA" or " VA " are acceptable, but not " 1VA ", " RVA", " VAT ", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use word boundary around the abbreviation:

```
/\b(VA)\b/
```

general regex:

```
/\b([A-Z]{2})\b/
```

Change your code to:

```
$stateAbbreviations  = Array('AL','AK','CA','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','LA','ME','NH','NJ','NY','NC','OR','MD','MA','MS','RI','SC','TX','VA','WA');

$query = "LESNER BRIDGE, VIRGINIA BEACH, VA 23453";
foreach($this->stateAbbreviations as $state) {
   if(preg_match("/\b($state)\b/", $query, $match)) {                    
      var_dump($match);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The end-of-line character in a regular expression is `$` and the beginning-of-line character is `^`, so this may be what you're looking for:

```
/(^|[ ,])[A-Z]{2}($|[ ,])/
```

This will match:

- Beginning of line, *or* a space, *or* a comma
- ...followed by 2 uppercase letters
- ...followed by an end of line, *or* a space, *or* a comma

Comment: you people who just spit our regex arouse me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+/
```

will match two uppercase letters with definite (one or more) whitespace on either side

Comment: Will not match if it's at the begining or at the end of the string.